# Accessing enum values from other class

Tags: c++, enums, typedef

In my project, I have an enum defined in a class, that is used throughout that class. During refactoring, that enum was moved to another class. So I simply `typedef`ed it in my original class, like this:

```
class A {
public:
  enum E {e1, e2};
};
class B {
public:
  typedef A::E E;
};
```

Now variable definitions, return values, function params, etc. work perfectly. Only when I want to access the values of the enum inside my second class, I still have to qualify them with the surroundig class's name,
e.g. `E e = A::e1;`

Is there a way to avoid this, or do I have to copy that into every occurance of the enum values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You put each enumeration into a nested class that you can typedef within your own class:

```
class A {
public:
  struct E { enum EnumType { e1, e2 } };
};
class B {
public:
  typedef A::E E;
};
```

Then it's just `E::EnumType` instead of `E` but you get full auto-importation.

Comment: And how would you access the enum values? I still have to write `E::EnumType e = E::e1;`

Comment: You do have to write that, which I feel is a small price to pay for not having to duplicate enumerated values, as long as you make E a meaningful name for the enumeration.

Answer (score 0):

If you're not above using c++11, you could have a look at enum classes.